# Calculations after Summing values in Drupal views with module aggregation plus

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, view, aggregate-functions

In Drupal 7, I use the module views aggregation plus.

There are 2 columns (A and B) which I apply a group aggregation of 'Average' and 'Sum' respectively. I want to have a 3rd column (C) which does a math expression (A - B) after the grouping. How can I achieve this? An example below

Before grouping

```
ID | Column A | Column B | Column C
1  | 5        | 10       | -5
1  | 5        | 10       | -5 
2  | 5        | 10       | -5
```

What I get currently

```
ID | Column A | Column B | Column C  
1  | 5        | 20       | -10
2  | 5        | 10       | -5
```

What I want to get

```
ID | Column A | Column B | Column C  
1  | 5        | 20       | -15
2  | 5        | 10       | -5
```

I tried retrieving the values of the summed field using devel module, and while I get this: $...['#views_contextual_links_info']['views_ui']['view']->style_plugin->rendered_fields[2]['expression_1']

I tried outputting that using Views PHP but it doesn't return back the correct value. I believe it is only returning back the value prior to being summed by the views aggregator plus.

Answer (score 1):

You can **add the field:** `Global: Math expression`.

It allows you to enter mathematical expressions such as `2 + 2 or sqrt(5)`.

As it supports Replacement Patterns of the fields you added before, you can easily enter `[field_column_A]-[field_column_B]`